# How to reply "Would tomorrow at 10:30am work for you?" in a formal way?

Tags: expressions

My professor emailed me to ask my available time: "Would tomorrow at 10:30am work for you?" 
How can I reply her email in a formal way.

Comment: *Yes, tomorrow at 10:30am would work for me. Thank you*.

Comment: "Yes." would be just right. "No." might require at least one alternative suggestion. I'm assuming the email you are responding to is copied below your reply.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for writing advice or it's asking about etiquette.

Answer (score 5):

*"Would tomorrow at 10:30am work for you?"*

Either

**"Yes, 10:30am tomorrow is good for me"**

or

**"No, I'm sorry I can't do 10:30am tomorrow.  I could do ..."**

Answer (score 0):

"Yes", or "certainly" are good enough as positive answers. In case of negatives, you can begin with "Unfortunately" or "I am afraid".

In any case you may want to verbalize the action here, such as "Yes, I am available to meet tomorrow at 10:30am" or "I am afraid that 10:30am is too early for me. Can we meet later in the afternoon."